# How to create a local repository to work with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, repository, workspace

So I been looking for instruction on how to create a local cvs repository as that what I once use for a team project. However I'm working on a couple of project alone. As my search on this site and Google turn up bare. I have two question; what would be the best repository to use in this situation with eclipse and how to create a local repository with it?

Edited:
Should mention that I'm working on window OS specifically Window 10.

The requirement is that the repository have to be set up offline on a pc with no active internet connection. Hope this narrow it down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) repository for each private project in your place. You can have a private repository there, but you can share it with others when you need to share it. You can use it as any other git repository. You can use it offline: Committing does not require internet connection, only pushing does.

I personally have never used eclipse's integrated version control support. You don't necessarily need eclipse integration: you can always use a sophisticated GUI git client like SourceTree or command line git.

Comment: Seem like it what I need. I just read the site info but just to clarify will this require internet connection for me to commit and such? I currently don't have a connection hence why I been looking for a local repository.